# Уведомления с телеграмм бота

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, уведомления, android-notification

Как написать расширение или бота которое бы отправляло новые объявления с сайта на почту или телеграмм ,например с раздела компьютеры ? Например авито. Куда копать ? В программировании ноль,

Comment: Начать изучать программирование, или заплатить и вам сделают

Answer (score 0):

В парсинге сайтов плох,но попробуй разобраться в библиотеках requests,telebot; вроде этого хватит чтобы распарсить сайт,написать бота в телеграмм и  дальше все обновления на сайте в нужном разделе отправлять тебе в тг через бота. В теории это в полне возможно